# Automation testing for iPhone

Tags: ios, automation, automated-tests

I want to test iOS application using the automation tools. I just have some primary knowledge of automation which does not include iOS automation application testing. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://bugfender.com/blog/best-automated-testing-tools-ios/

Answer (score 2):

Appium Studio is an enhanced version of open-source Appium developed by Experitest to make Appium testing even better. It cuts the effort and cost of developing and running an Appium based mobile test automation program. Check out [here](https://experitest.com/) for more information.
They also offer object spy and code export feature along with a set of cloud devices for testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are different Mobile Automation tools available in the Market,

1. Appium - Highly used for Android and iPhones
2. Appium Studio from Experitest
3. Katlon Studio
4. XCUITEST - Only for iPhones
5. Robot Framework

Answer (score 0):

Best tools for mobile testings is :
**Calabash**

1. It is FREE and since Calabash harnesses Cucumber functionality, which means that tests can be written in plain English rather than labyrinthine chains of code.
2. Calabash is by far one of the leading open-source test framework for cross-platform (mobile) native test automation.

**It offers**:

1. Ability to write in plain English
2. Capacity to test both local and hybrid apps
3. Xamarin and Cucumber functionality

**Xamarin** provides a portal to over 1,000 different devices in the cloud, which have been put there so you can test your apps. Once you’ve written your test, just log into the Xamarin test cloud and away you go.

Answer (score -1):

One of the most used Test Automation Tool nowadays is [Appium](https://github.com/appium/appium).

I myself used it professionally and it worked really well. It helps you with actions such as finding elements and interacting with them, to name a few. It is open source, cross-platform - enables you to test on Android, iOS and more - and multi-language - meaning you can write your tests using many different programming languages such as Ruby, Java, Python, C# etc.

Check their page to see if it really fit your needs: [appium.io](http://appium.io/)